# How to fix translated text over controls in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, label

I have got labels in my Windows Forms application which are placed next to controls.
When I change my language options to another language, the text needs more space now it covers my control.

Are there any ways to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

No magic here I'm afraid. You have to try making your labels as (reasonably) wide as possible to accomodate each of your supported languages. Don't use `AutoSize` property here.

If labels appears on the left, have your text aligned to the right using the `TextAlign` property. This way they should always appear close to your control without ever overlapping them.

Answer (score 1):

Also try to use containers to design your forms: `TableLayoutPanel`, `FlowLayoutPanel`. Controls that are placed in their cells, are autosized and wordwrapped correctly in most cases.

Comment: It's good advice but it's also one to be cautious with because if you don't know what you do your (maybe too much) dynamic layout can get heavily deformed. Still, +1.